Explicit isomorphism between $(R/I)[x]$ and $R[x]/I[x]$, where $I$ is an ideal of the commutative ring $R$
I know that defining the map $\varphi: R[x] \to R[x]/I[x]$ by $$\varphi(a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n)=(a_0+I)+(a_1+I)x+...+(a_n+I)x^n$$ then $\varphi$ is a ring homomorphism with kernel $I[x]$, so using an isomorphism theorem we obtain the result.
My question is: Is there a way to describe the ring isomomorphism without using isomomorphism theorems? In other words, can we find an EXPLICIT isomomorphism?
Thank you!

Instead, find an onto homomorphism $R[x]\to (R/I)[x]$ which is onto, and then show the kernel is $I[x].$

@ThomasAndrews Even though OP ostensibly says otherwise, that's exactly what they've done.

Ah,yes, didn't actually see the definition because the order was wrong. @BrianMoehring

OP: The isomorphism theorems do give explicit isomorphisms.  They just let you avoid extra steps.

What result? You are relying on the title of your MSE question that is needed to make sense of the text in the body. Please make the bodies of your questions self-contained.

Whenever you have found

an explicit homomorphism $\varphi : R \to S$,
an explicit proof that $\varphi$ is surjective,
an explicit proof of  $\ker(\varphi) = I$,

then you can just look at the proof of the "isomorphism theorem" to find

an explicit isomorphism $R/I \to S$.

It is just given by mapping an element $[r]$ of $R/I$, represented by some ring element $r \in R$, to its image $\varphi(r)$ under the given homomorphism.
In your specific example, this means that the specific isomorphism is given by
$$R[x] / I[x] \to (R/I)[x], \quad [a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n] \mapsto [a_0] + [a_1] x + \cdots + [a_n] x^n,$$
where as before I denote by $[r]$ the image of a ring element in its respective quotient ring (or $[r]_I$ if the ideal is ambiguous).
Commutativity of $R$ is not required.

PS. I don't recommend to write $[r]$ as a coset since cosets are an irrelevant implementation detail of quotient rings, and are also sources of confusion. See my answers here or here what really matters. It is a pity that the fundamental thm. on homomorphisms is only listed deep down as a property on the wiki page on quotient rings. It is more than that.

Precisely what do you mean by an "explciit" hom and an "explicit" proof?

The same as you.

But I never used that language, Again, what do you mean?
